# Xcode 11.6 having error while importing custom framework: Module compiled with Swift 5.3 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.2.4

Tags: swift5, xcode12, swift-custom-framework, xcode11.6

> Module compiled with Swift 5.3 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.2.4
> compiler:
> /Users/myMac/Desktop/SampleAdopter_1/SampleAdopter_1/Custom.framework/Modules/Custom.swiftmodule/armv7-apple-ios.swiftmodule

We are creating a custom framework using CI Jenkins build which is having Xcode 12 and try to import in another project which is using Xcode 11.6 and that shows the above error.

We have tried "build_distribution_flag" - Yes in the custom framework but we having the same error.
We are installing our custom framework by using pod into projects.

Comment: We are facing same issue.Setting build_distribution_flag to Yes Not working

Comment: Is it Swift restriction to always match with complier version if we create custom framework with specific Swift version in Xcode ?

Comment: It's compiler, not complier. And usually you need the same _or a newer version_. Your 5.2.4 compiler cannot know what a 5.3 compiler is doing, but a 5.3 compiler should know how a 5.2.4 compiler works.

Comment: Custom framework is created from  5.3 compiler which is latest and I am using it in  lower version of compiler so it should work .... right ? because I have tried wise versa but every time they need same compiler version of Custom framework as well as integrated project as well

Comment: We are facing the same issue but unable to resolve it. Please provide the solution